# Display visualforce page of a managed package on the Force.com site

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a visualforce component from a managed package. I created a visualforce page with that component and want to display it on force.com site.
But it shows 'Insufficient permissions: secure query included inaccessible field'
I believe i have given all required permissions for classes, objects for the profile..
Any suggessions how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.[Insufficient permissions: secure query included inaccessible field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI8mp.png)

I gave all the permissions to the site user of visualforce - classes, custom setting, visual force page but I am still getting the error.